# regular expression in java for first three letters in a sentence

Tags: java, regex

how to write an regular expression in java for the sentence that is similar below and that  should match only first three characters of the sentence

```
ins(clear(icl>remove>do,plf>thing,obj>thing,ins>thing).@entry.@past,evidence(icl>indication>thing))
```

i tried this code but it also matches clear,evidence in the sentence....

```
String pattern2="[-a-z0-9R:._-`&=*'`~\"\\+[\\s]]+[\\(]";  

Pattern r2 = Pattern.compile(pattern2);
Matcher m2 = r2.matcher(line);


 while (m2.find()) 
 {
     rel = m2.group();
     rel = rel.substring(0, rel.length()-1).trim();                 
     System.out.println("The relation are " + rel); 
 }
```

Comment: `sentence.substring(0,3)` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should remove firstly all non-letters

```
String result = string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

And then just taking first three symbols :

```
result.substring(0, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only get match from start of the line you can add `^` at start of your regex (before `[`).

If you want to be sure that matched part before `(` will have 3 characters don't use `..]+` but `..]{3}`.

Also if you want to just check if some characters are after interesting part but you don't want to include them use look-ahead mechanism `(?=...)` like in your case `(?=[\\(])` or simpler `(?=[(])` - there is no need to escape `(` with `\\` and `[]`at the same time.

So maybe change your pattern to

```
String pattern2 = "^[-a-z0-9R:._-`&=*'`~\"+\\s]{3}(?=[(])";
```

Also I am not sure if `` _-` `` is what you mean since it will create range of characters between `_` and `` ` ``

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches the first 3 chars:

```
^...
```

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
String pattern2="^[^\\(]+";
```

Comment: ... matches up to (but excluding) the first open paranthesis, if that is what you need.

Comment: in  that there are many lines but it prints only first 3 characters of 1st line...